# Google Autocomplete Map Search

Tags: html

These two websites is how I want the auto complete to function like, please can you tell me how they have managed to do this as the one my developer has installed doesn't bring up all the locations.

Example: if you type in Kent, it only brings us the towns in Kent, but it doesn’t Show KENT UK, as well is which we want; the same goes for Essex etc., so he obviously has configured it wrong.

Problem is he's based in India, so explaining it is difficult.

https://www.evolutionjobs.com/uk/
https://www.ncp.co.uk/find-a-car-park/

Answer (score 0):

They are using '**Geocoding Component Restrictions**';

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-component-restriction

Hope this solves your problem. But without your website it's hard to exactly give you the right solution.

Comment: Thanks Arthur , the website is still been developed I will try and get you a link, thanks a millon those :)